# Pass JavaScript object/hash to Handlebars helper?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, templating-engine

Is it possible to pass a JavaScript object/hash into a Handlebars helper call? I'd like to do something like this:

```
<label>Label here</label>
{{#textField {'id':'text_field_1', 'class':'some-class', size:30} }}{{/textField}}
<p>Help text here.</p>
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9HCF/). Currently it produces the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 3:
...bel>  {{#textField {'id':'text_field_1'
----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
```

Alternatively I could probably do this and split on ',', but I am not fond of the syntax:

```
{{#textField "'id'='text_field_1','class'='some-class',size=30"}}{{/textField}}
```

NOTE: I specifically do NOT want to pass data/attributes (id, class, size, etc.) into the template() method as a JSON object. I want everything in the template.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved. I did this:

Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('textField', function(options) {
    var attributes = [];

    for (var attributeName in options.hash) {
      attributes.push(attributeName + '="' + options.hash[attributeName] + '"');
    }

    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<input type="text" ' + attributes.join(' ') + ' />');
});
```

And the template:

```
<label>Label here</label>
{{textField id="text_field_1" class="some-class" size="30" data-something="data value"}}
<p>Help text here.</p>
```

Per [the documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) (bottom of the page), you can pass in a variable number of parameters to a helper method, and they will be available in options.hash (assuming "options" is a parameter to your helper method). And what's also nice about this is that you can use named parameters, and parameter order doesn't matter.

Comment: How can we pass a text&value dynamically?. Tried the following but this couldn't workout. Anyway?
`{{textField id="text_field_1" class="some-class" size="30" data-something="data value"{{this.number}} }}`
Actually i need to append value to data-attribute with text

Answer (score 10):

I found another best way to pass objects.

**Template:**

```
{{textField dataAttribs='{"text":"Hello", "class": "text-field"}'}}
```

**Helper:**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('textField', function(options) {
    var attribs;

    attribs = JSON.parse(options.hash.dataAttribs);
    console.log(attribs.text + " -- " + attribs.class);
    ......
    ........
});
```

[JSFiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/sathyamoorthi/X9HCF/2/)

Comment: +1 for retaining the hash mapping as originally asked for by the poster — though I tend to like the API of the accepted answer a bit more as it mimics HTML attributes.

Comment: The accepted answer works best when you know the keys upfront. If you don't, this is a decent workaround.