# Is it possible to access the data that is sent to handlebars through JS inside the template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

So lets say I generate content from an external handlebars template (through AJAX)

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        source    = data;
        template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
        //execute the callback if passed
        if (callback) callback(template);
    }
});
```

Now inside my template.handlebars I output the data I sent using the tags {{this}} etc.
But I also include some javascript that are only meant for that template on the bottom of the template (which works fine). However I need to access some of the data sent to the template inside the javascript, is it possible?

A really dumb example which I know doesn't work but should explain what I'm after incase it's unclear. So this could be an example of my template.handlebars file:

```
<h1>{{question}}</h1>

<script>
//want to access the data sent to template in the JS included
(function($) { //wrap to local scope
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //this doesn't work ofcourse.. but should explain what I'm after
        var question = {{question}};
        console.log(question)
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas on how to do that? For me it feels clean to include the JS that is only meant for the particular template this way.

Comment: var question = "{{question}}"; try like this, if it is string.

Comment: Thanks, that works for strings but not objects nor arrays. I guess I could use JSON and parse that though! If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compile Handlebars template they just return you string by replacing `{{expression}}`.

So you have to work on each datatypes. For strings use like this.

```
var question = "{{question}}";
```

integers should not have any problem. They can be directly placed like this.

```
var question = {{question}};
```

I have already worked for objects. You can call helpers for objects and arrays.

refer this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085301/pass-javascript-object-hash-to-handlebars-helper/18546138#18546138) to handle objects.

Comment: Thanks! creating helpers for accessing objects is a solution I was aware of. What I did now was to add the data I needed in my JS with JSON.stringify() and use JSON.parse("{{objname}}"); to retrieve it.